# If $f:R\to [-\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{2})$, $f(x)=\tan^{-1} (x^4-x^2 -\frac 74 +\tan^{-1} \alpha)$, find $\alpha$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

I simplified the expression to
$$\tan (f(x)) = (x^2 -\frac 12)^2 + (\tan^{-1} \alpha -2)$$

How do I solve further???

Comment: What do you want to solve for ?$\alpha$ in terms of $x,f(x)$?

Comment: @ArchisWelankar $alpha$ is a singular value